# Getting HREF of an <a> tag with preg_match_all and curl

Tags: php, html, curl, preg-match-all

It's been a couple of days now that I am trying to find a way to solve my problem. I use CURL to get the content of a webpage and then use prey_match_all to use the content on my style, but I've got a problem when it's time to find some < a > tags in the document.

I want preg_match_all to find all < a > tags that are followed by a < strong > tag and than store all href values of these < a > tags in a array variable.

Here's what I've thought :

```
preg_match_all("~(<a href=\"(.*)\"><strong>\w+<\/strong>)~iU", $result, $link);
```

It's returning me :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) )
```

Can somebody help me please !!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: The `<center>` cannot hold it is too late.

Comment: http://php.net/preg_match_all make sure that $result and $link are the right way around... Other than that, we'd need to see some example `html` to write a `regex`...

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you go with [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

This code should do the trick...

```
<?php

/**
* @author Jay Gilford
* @edited KHMKShore:stackoverflow
*/

/**
* get_links()
* 
* @param string $url
* @return array
*/
function get_links($url) {

  // Create a new DOM Document to hold our webpage structure
  $xml = new DOMDocument();

  // Load the url's contents into the DOM (the @ supresses any errors from invalid XML)
  @$xml->loadHTMLFile($url);

  // Empty array to hold all links to return
  $links = array();

  //Loop through each <a> and </a> tag in the dom
  foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    //if it has a strong tag in it, save the href link.
    if (count($link->getElementsByTagName('strong')) > 0) {
        $links[] = array('url' => $link->getAttribute('href'), 'text' => $link->nodeValue);
    }
  }

  //Return the links
  return $links;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much KHMKShore ! You were right, DOMDocument was the right thing to do ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

firstly, your regex can fail easily

```
<a alt="cow > moo" href="cow.php"><strong>moo</strong></a>
```

second your regex is slightly out, the following will work:

```
~(<a href="(.*)"><strong>\w+</strong></a>)~
```

thirdly, and most important, if you want to be guaranteed to extract what you want without ever failing, like @KHMKShore has pointed out, DOMDocument is the best path.